# How to optimize building-tree algorithm?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I wrote an algorithm to build a tree (like directories in operating system).
It is not small but I'll try to describe my solution.

Let's see my code:

```
public class TreeNode
{
    protected TreeNode(string part)
        : this(part, -1, null)

    private TreeNode(
       string part, 
       int level, 
       TreeNode? parent)
    {
        Part = part;
        Level = level;
        Parent = parent;
        Root = parent?.Root ?? this;
    }

    private bool _updateEnqueued;
    public string Part {get;set;}
    public int Level {get;}
    public TreeNode? Parent {get;}
    public TreeNode Root {get;}

    public bool Add(
      string[] subTopic,
      MqttDelivery delivery)
      => Add(subTopic, Level + 1; delivery);

    public void ForceResync()
      => Root.Update();

    public void EnqueueUpdate()
    {
       if(_updateEnqueued)
          return;
 
       _updateEnqueued = true;
       Dispatcher.UIThread.Post(
           Update, 
           DispatcherPriority.Background);
    }

    private bool Add(string[] topic, int level, MqttDelivery delivery)
    {
       if(level >= topic.Length)
       {
          Topic = delivery.Topic;
          Header = delivery.Header?.ToJsonString(true);
          Payload = delivery.Payload?.ToJsonString(true);
          Delivery = delivery;

          AddToHistory(delivery);
          return false;
       }
       
       var part = topic[level];
       if(!_treeChildren.Value.TryGetValue(part, out var trie))
       {
          TopicsCount++;
          _treeChildren.Value.Add(part, trie = new TreeNode(part,level,this));
       }

       MessagesCount++;
       trie.Add(topic, level + 1, delivery);
       return true;
    }

    private void AppendItems()
    {
       _updateEnqueued = false;
       var flatTreeList = new AvaloniaList<TreeNode>();
       AppendItems(flatTreeList, this);
       _visibleChildren = flatTreeList;
    }
    
    private void AppendItems(
        AvaloniaList<TreeNode> flatTreeList,
        TreeNode treeNode)
   {
      flatTreeList.Add(treeNode);
      if(!treeNode.IsExpanded)
         return;

      foreach(var ch in treeNode._treeChildren.Value)
         AppendItems(flatTreeList, ch.Value);
   } 

   public void Update()
   {
      AppendItems();
      Root.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Root.VisibleChildren));
   }

   public void AddToHistory(MqttDelivery mqttMessage)
   {
      while(UiHistoryMessages.Count >= 30)
         UiHistoryMessages.RemoveAt(UiHistoryMessages.Count - 1);

      UiHistoryMessages.Insert(0, new ReceivedHistoryMessage{..});
   }
}
```

TreeNode is just a node, so we need a root. Let's see:

```
public class TreeRoot
    : TreeNode
{
    public TreeRoot()
        : base("")
    {
        var timer = new Timer(1000);
        timer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void OnTimerElapsed(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Root.EnqueueUpdate();
    }
    
}
```

I decided to update tree every sec so I added `Root.EnqueueUpdate();` to `OnTimerElapsed`

I create TreeRoot only once and then just call `ForceRecync`:

```
var root = new TreeRoot {IsExpanded = false};
root.ForceResync();
```

My problem is following: items are constantly being added to the tree and the application consumes a lot of memory over time, which is not cleared! 80mb, 100mb, after 30 min it becomes 400mb.
I don't understand what can I do with it..

I tested the count of items in HistoryCollection:
// recursively get all UiHistoryMessages

```
var nodes = TreeRoot.Flatten().ToList();
var historyMessages = new List<ReceivedHistoryMessage>();
foreach(var node in nodes)
{
   var collection = node.UiHistoryMessages;
   foreach(var col in collection)
   {
      historMessages.Add(message);
   }
}

var count = historyMessages.Count;
```

when my application used 400 MB of memory, the `count` was +- 10000 and `nodes` count was +- 2000..
I don't think it is too much and I don't understand why my memory isn't being cleared.
Help me, please

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to update all the nodes again and again? If it is a shallow tree where all items are visible then it may not be a problem at all. Otherwise, there is no need to update (or even populate initially) unexpanded nodes. In other words, populate nodes 'on demand'. I did that maybe 20 years ago in another language but idea is same: https://www.levelextreme.com/Home/ShowHeader?Activator=23&ID=39249

Comment: But it's not a problem. I already did it in AppendItems method: 
`if (!treeNode.IsExpanded) return;`

Comment: it means I don't update not expanded values

Comment: How do you know that your tree is where the memory is going? Try following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/debug-memory-leak and see if there might be some other place where memory is leaking.